# Using Python Pip from behind Sophos firewall with certificate

Tags: firewall, python, ssl-certificate, pip, sophos

I have this problem using pip at my workplace since the System Admin has started using the Sophos XG Firewall with a custom CA installed in my windows local system and firefox. I don't have any proxy settings configured in any of the clients.

When I try something this happens.

```
C:\Users\talha.ahmed>pip install objdict
Collecting objdict
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError
(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003A3B4A8>, 'Connecti
on to 10.10.2.124 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/objdict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError
(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003A3B588>, 'Connecti
on to 10.10.2.124 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/objdict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError
(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003A3BC88>, 'Connecti
on to 10.10.2.124 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/objdict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError
(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003A3B780>, 'Connecti
on to 10.10.2.124 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/objdict/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError
(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003A3BB38>, 'Connecti
on to 10.10.2.124 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/objdict/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement objdict (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for objdict
```

Note that it says it is getting a timeout connecting to 10.10.2.124 (which is not the gateway/proxy), instead of pypi.python.org, which maybe some kind of local server or a modem or something.

However, I can access https://pypi.python.org/simple/objdict/ using my firefox and download the packages manually. When I do I can see firefox using the *fake* sophos certificate and everything seems to work fine.

I have already tried using `--cert` option on pip and tried adding the cert to the C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\cacert.pem file. Using the `--proxy` options in various combinations as suggested by various discussions on SO and SU.

So can you suggest should be my next approach?

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away when used the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables to specify the proxy for pip. Apparently pip was ignoring the `--proxy` option from the command line, however it read the environment variables.

Pip uses proxy settings from the windows system's *"internet options"* that is used by chrome and internet explorer but are ignored by firefox. In my particular case internet options were set to use the proxy at 10.10.2.124 (wrong), which I also did not need.

Removing the proxy check from *"internet options"* actually alleviates the need to specify the environment variable. The only thing left to tell is the certificate which can be done by using the --cert option.